# request.user.is_authenticated is always false in Django rest framework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I am using allauth for authentication in drf. I was able to register new users and login with the credentials.
The login api return response something like this:

```
{
 "key" : "<some token>"
}
```

Now I have 1 more API the code for which is

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    def lol(request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse("Authenticated")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Not Authenticated")
```

But this is always returning not authenticated
my api call look like this[image]

Here is the list of installed apps in my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_auth',
'django.contrib.sites',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'rest_auth.registration',

'api.user',
'api.activity',
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're using functional views? If so did you add `@api_view` decorator to the view?

If so did you add `authentication_classes=[TokenAuthentication]` keyword argument? That's imperative to make token Auth work.

Either that or set the following in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was missing @api_view.